# Set of unit vectors such that among any three there is an orthogonal pair

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

I was fascinated by the solutions of Problem 8 of the [IMC 2021 contest](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/index.php?year=2021), which can be summarized as:

**Theorem 1.** Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_N$ be distinct unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that among any three there is an orthogonal pair. Then $N\leq 2n$.

Note that $N=2n$ is achieved by the union of two disjoint orthonormal bases. Particularly elegant is the [third official solution](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?year=2021&section=problems&item=prob8s), probably due to the [only successful solver](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?act=results&year=2021&by=p8) Ioannis Tzachristas, which proceeds by comparing the trace of the Gram matrix $G=(\langle v_i,v_j\rangle)$ and its square. Now let us assume that $N=2n$. Then the third solution eventually yields that the eigenvalues of $G$ are $0$ and $2$, both with multiplicity $n$. In particular, $G^2=2G$, whence
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\langle v_i,v_k\rangle\langle v_k,v_j\rangle=2\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$$
holds for any pair $(i,j)$. If we multiply both sides by $x_i x_j$ and sum up over the pairs $(i,j)$, we get the following geometric condition:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\langle v,v_k\rangle^2=2\langle v,v\rangle,\qquad v\in\mathbb{R}^n.\tag{$\ast$}$$
So we obtained

**Theorem 2.** Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_{2n}$ be distinct unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that among any three there is an orthogonal pair. Then the vectors form a [tight frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(linear_algebra)#Tight_frames) with frame constant $2$.

**Question.** Can we classify the systems occurring in Theorem 2? For example, is it true that the vectors form two disjoint orthonormal bases?

For example, if $v_1,\dotsc, v_n$ form an orthonormal basis, then $(\ast)$ shows that $v_{n+1},\dotsc, v_{2n}$ also form an orthonormal basis.

**Added.** Vector systems as in the post are called "nearly orthogonal". The contest problem was originally asked by Paul Erdős. Theorem 1 is due to Rosenfeld (1991), and the simple proof alluded to above was already found by Deaett (2011). The paper by Deaett (2011) also anwers my last question: the answer is "yes" for $n\leq 4$, but "no" for $n\geq 5$. Thanks to Christian Bernert for the valuable comments!

Comment: The article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379510006610 shows that starting from $n=5$, there are examples which are not a union of two orthonormal bases. So it seems that in general the structure of such sets can be quite complicated.

Comment: Indeed, this makes the problem quite subtle, because it shows that naive inductive approaches are doomed to fail.

Comment: @ChristianBernert: Thanks for your valuable comments. I added an "Added" section.